# BigQuery Data Transfer Services - python client library

Tags: python, google-bigquery, data-transfer

Currently, we have lots of requests in scheduling a BigQuery data transfer for DoubleClick Campaign Manager. So we follow the instruction here to use Data Transfer V2.0. It requires manual set up and permission with user account.

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/doubleclick-campaign-transfer

However, I notice that Data Transfer Service support REST-API

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/datatransfer/rest/

But it looks like the REST-API only supports version=v1. My questions:

- What are the differences between REST-API v1.0 and Data Transfer V2.0?
- Can I use the REST-API with Data Transfer V2.0?

I am looking for a python client library of "bigquery data transfer services", specially for how to launch the bigquery job to run or schedule a backfill to load DCM data to BigQuery.

How could I do the above works to set up "bigquery data transfer" automatically with service account instead of manual set up with user account?

Thanks!

Comment: just as fyi - you can do all this in magnus with rest api - most likely you know that :o)

Comment: Sure, thanks Mikhail. Let me try that instead.

Comment: i think i already have an example there for using `https://storagetransfer.googleapis.com/v1/transferJobs` for setting and scheduling transfer from S3 to GCS. so it should be similar (at least conceptually)

Answer (score 0):

The Data Transfer Service API version is currently v1. It does [support](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/doubleclick-campaign-transfer) DoubleClick Campaign Manager "Data Transfer v2". They are two different sets of APIs: Data Transfer Service vs. DoubleClick Campaign Manager Data Transfer.